# Background music in thymeleaf

Tags: html, thymeleaf

Hi how can I play background music in thymeleaf? Basic ways lose

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="/static/hikariare.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

And I get something like this:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute name "controls" associated with an element type "audio" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

Answer (score 0):

For most attributes like that (required, controls, etc) in XHTML you have to set them like this. (You'll probably have to end the source tag as well.)

```
<audio controls="controls">
    <source src="/static/hikariare.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></source>
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring-Boot and `spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf` dependency, you should add

```
<properties>
    <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
    <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.1.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```

to your `pom.xml`.

This forces maven to use Thymeleaf 3. The default Thymeleaf 2 only supports HTML/XHMTL and not pure HTML5 (`<audio controls>` is HTML5)

More informations here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-use-thymeleaf-3